# call child function from parent in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

**My parent component**

```
import EditReview from './partials/editReview'

class VenueDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="place-review-text">
        <EditReview {...this.props}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**My child component**

```
class EditReview extends Component {
  onEditClick(review, editIndex) {
    console.log('ppp')
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, user, pristine, index, commentCrossClick } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Field
          name="content"
          component={renderTextArea}
          className="form-control"
          label="Write your review..."
          rows={2}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EditReview
```

I need to call `onEditClick` from the parent component. I tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent) but doesn't work.

Kindly help me

**Edit**

After upgrade  I am getting this

```
Error in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactServerRendering.js
Module not found: 'react/lib/React' in /home/user/ashish/LTC/lovethesecities-frontend/node_modules/react-dom/lib
```

After resolving all the errors **[call child function from parent in react 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126272/call-child-function-from-parent-in-react-16)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React docs have a example of this using refs

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

I’m also wondering the use case of wanting to do this, maybe some context could help with an answer?

Comment: My use case is that I have <Modal> <Form /> </Modal>. So when form is submitted - we have to call method of the modal to close it. And it is a method in modal cause I have to apply some CSS and then remove the modal itself. (The goal is to have animated removing of the modal . And I keep it in the modal so don't repeat it in every child.)

Comment: (Of course, if you have a better idea - I'm all ears :) ...)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this:

```
import EditReview from './partials/editReview'

class VenueDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="place-review-text">
        <EditReview ref={Ref => this.child=Ref } {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and call the function in parent component as `this.child.onEditClick(param1,param2)`

**EDIT1**:

if you have to do it with react 15.x itself what you can do it is create  the function in parent and pass it as a prop to child

Comment: why dont you create that function in parent and pass to child as a prop that seems to be the only option...

Comment: yes but onClick handler is in parent component... Ok kindly wait I am upgrading