# call child function from parent in react 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After upgrading to react **16** I am getting `null` in `console.log(this.child)`

**My parent component**

```
import EditReview from './partials/editReview'

class VenueDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }
  editButtonClick = () => {
    console.log(this.child)
    this.child.current.onEditClick()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="pull-right" onClick={() => this.editButtonClick(review, i)}>edit</button>
        <div className="place-review-text">
          <EditReview {...this.props}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**My child component**

```
class EditReview extends Component {
  onEditClick(review, editIndex) {
    console.log('ppp')
  }

  render() {
    return ()
  }
}

export default EditReview
```

I need to call `onEditClick` from the parent component. I tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent) but doesn't work.

Kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the ref:

```
<EditReview {...this.props} ref={this.child} />
```

Also, you don't need to use inline arrow function:

```
onClick={() => this.editButtonClick(review, i)}
// ------^^^^^ not required
// because, you're already using public class method
```

Just use:

```
onClick={this.editButtonClick(review, i)}
```

Define your method like this:

```
editButtonClick = (review, index) => { // to access review, i
```

Comment: Inline arrow function because I am using child component  in loop... And ***render() {
  return () // it's null
}*** it is just to simplify the code in above question

Comment: loop doesn't require inline arrow function.

Comment: even to simplify the code, you may at least show oneline dummy content. don't do that again when you ask next question.