# all the values of clearAllSearchCriteria should be passed to NoResult component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am new to react.
- I am trying to call child method from parent in reactjs.
- Here NoResult component is present in SportsCardList component and SportsCardList component is present in Sports-search-favorites-tab
- so here three different components are involving.
- ***when I click the Clear All Search Criteria div all the values of clearAllSearchCriteria should be passed to NoResult component and from there the values should be passed to Sports-search-favorites-tab.js***
- I used the below link and implemented but I am getting an error TypeError: _this.alfoRef.handleDeleteFromParent is not a function.
  [call child function from parent in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125409/call-child-function-from-parent-in-reactjs)
- can you guys tell me how to pass teh value from child to parent since another component is present in the middle. so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my relevant code snippets alone below since my codebase is big

**TypeError: _this.alfoRef.handleDeleteFromParent is not a function**

**granfather component 1
Sports-search-favorites-tab.js**

```
import SportsCardList from './SportsCardList';

clearAllSearchCriteria = () => {
    console.log('clearAllSearchCriteria');
    this.alfoRef.handleDeleteFromParent();
}

   render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardContent style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
          <Typography className={classes.noResultContainer}>
            {/*<div className={classes.noResultContainer}>*/}
            <div className={classes.noResultContainerItemText}>No Results Were Returned</div>

            <CardActions className={classes.noResultContainerItem}>
              <div className={classes.clearAll} onClick={this.props.clearAllSearchCriteria} >Clear All Search Criteria</div>
              {/*<div onClick={() => props.clicked(clearAllSearchVar)}/>*/}
              {/*<div onClick={() => props.clicked(clearAllSearchCriteria)}> Clear All Search Criteria</div>*/}


            </CardActions>

            {/*
            <CardActions className={classes.noResultContainerItem}>
              <Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer("right", true)} size="small">Create task for Custom Payment Build</Button>
            </CardActions>*/}

            {/*</div>*/}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <Drawer
          style={{ width: 500 }}
          anchor="right"
          open={this.state.right}
          onClose={this.toggleDrawer("right", false)}
        >
          <div
            tabIndex={0}
            role="button"
          >
            {/*sideList*/}
            {/*sports advanced search for tab codes */}

            <TabDemo />
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </Card>


    );

  }
```

**parent 1(middle component2)
SportsCardList.js**

```
import NoResult from './no-result';

clearAllSearchCriteria = () =>{
    console.log('clearAllSearchCriteria');
    this.props.clearAllSearchCriteria();
}

<NoResult clearAllSearchCriteria={this.clearAllSearchCriteria}/>
```

**child(grandson) component 3
no-result.js**

```
return (
  <Card className={classes.card}>
    <CardContent style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
      <Typography className={classes.noResultContainer}>
        {/*<div className={classes.noResultContainer}>*/}
        <div className={classes.noResultContainerItemText}>No Results Were Returned</div>

        <CardActions className={classes.noResultContainerItem}>
          <div className={classes.clearAll} onClick={this.props.clearAllSearchCriteria} >Clear All Search Criteria</div>
          {/*<div onClick={() => props.clicked(clearAllSearchVar)}/>*/}
          {/*<div onClick={() => props.clicked(clearAllSearchCriteria)}> Clear All Search Criteria</div>*/}


        </CardActions>


        {/*
        <CardActions className={classes.noResultContainerItem}>
          <Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer("right", true)} size="small">Create task for Custom Payment Build</Button>
        </CardActions>*/}

        {/*</div>*/}
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>

  </Card>


);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Grandfather component**:

```
clearAllHandler = (clearAllSearchVar) => {
// Work with clearAllSearchVar
}
<Father clicked={this.clearAllHandler} />
```

**Father component**:

```
<Son clicked={props.clicked} />
```

**Son component**:

```
<div onClick={() => props.clicked(clearAllSearchVar)}/>
```

You should fill `clearAllSearchVar` in the `<Son />` component and whenever you click it the variable is passed to the `clearAllHandler` function in `<Grandfather />` component which passed a reference to the function down to his **grand** `<Son />` through props via the `<Father />`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: so my no result component will turn like this right ``` <NoResult clearAllSearchCriteria={props.clearAllSearchCriteria}/> ```

Comment: Can you say it in the family metaphor, please? So, I can better understand.

Comment: hey if I updated all your code in my child component file <div onClick={() => props.clicked(clearAllSearchCriteria)}> Clear All Search Criteria</div>  and it throws two different errors --->  Line 170:  'props' is not defined                   no-undef
  Line 170:  'clearAllSearchCriteria' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: it would be great if you update in my code snippet since its so confusing :(

Comment: did you miss this keyword in your answer

Comment: You need to pass props the the function constructor of your component like this: clearAllSearchCriteria = (props) =>{...

Comment: hey I have mentioned three different files in my question, can you tell me in which file...can you directly update in my code snippet

Comment: Give me a second, please.

Answer (score 0):

**Grandfather:**

```
import SportsCardList from './SportsCardList';

clearAllSearchCriteria = (clearAllSearchVar) => {
    //Work here with clearAllSearchVar
    console.log('clearAllSearchCriteria');
    this.alfoRef.handleDeleteFromParent();
}

<div>
    {/*<NoResult />*/}
    <SportsCardList clicked={this.clearAllSearchCriteria}/>

    <Dialog
        isOpen={this.state.open}
        onClose={() => {
            this.setState({ open: false });
        }}
    />
</div>
```

**Father** SportsCardList.js:

```
    const SportsCardList = props => {
    <NoResult clicked={props.clicked}/>
}
```

**Son** NoResult.js:

```
const NoResult = props => {
<CardActions className={classes.noResultContainerItem}>
    <div className={classes.clearAll} onClick={() => props.clicked(clearAllSearchCriteria)} >Clear All Search Criteria</div>
</CardActions>
}
```

Just make sure you fill clearAllSearchCriteria variable.

Comment: I updated the child component code in my question, can you update your answer similar to that since if i use your child component code its throwing this errors ```  Line 177:  'props' is not defined                   no-undef
  Line 177:  'clearAllSearchCriteria' is not defined  no-undef  ```

Comment: hey sorry to say even if I update your code in grandparent component its throwing syntax errors at this line  const SportsCardList = props => {   . Can you some how help me